# Why setOnClickListener() did not work for GridView (AdapterView)

Tags: android

When I try to set click listener for GridView (AdapterView), the program breakdown and Logcat : "Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView".

Add: Why the mechanism(Adapterview could not call on click) work like this ?

Comment: instead use `setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: question is not clear give some more info along with code..

Comment: O Lord! Please post your code and log-cat trace.

Comment: Clear define, what you want is whole GridView's click, or GridItem's click ?

Comment: Whole GridView, and how it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onItemClick`

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Added in API level 1
Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to setOnItemClickListener function.